# How synchronized is working in the following threading code and what is the code flow?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, runnable

```
class ThreadA {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
    b.start();
    synchronized (b) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
            b.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    }
}}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
int total;

public void run() {
    synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            total += i;
        }
        notify();
    }
}}
```

I am unable to understand the code flow and how run method is being called in the above programs.
When the object is of class `ThreadB` then why `main()` thread of `ThreadA` is able to synchronize object `b`. Apart from that when `wait()` is encountered by the `main()` thread, how the executions shifts to `run()` in `ThreadB`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does main() reaches to the synchronized block even before ThreadB's run() is able to execute.

Your program has a *race condition*.

After `main()` calls `b.start()` there are two threads running, unsynchronized, and they race to lock (i.e., synchronize on) the `b` object.  There is no way to predict which thread will lock it first.

If the `main()` thread locks it first, then it will call `b.wait()`.  That will temporarily unlock the `b` object, and allow the other thread to run.  The other thread will do its work, call `b.notify()` and exit the `synchronized` block.  As soon as it exits, the `main()` thread will be able to return from the `wait()` call.

If the second thread is first to lock the `b` object, the behavior will be different:  It will do its work, call `notify()`, and return.  But the `notify()` call will do nothing in that case because the `main()` thread will be blocked trying to enter the `synchronized` block.  It won't be waiting in the `b.wait()` call, and `notify()` doesn't do anything if there isn't any other thread waiting.

So what will happen next in that case is, when the `ThreadB` thread leaves the `synchronized` block, the `main()` thread will be able to enter it and call `wait()`.  The program will hang at that point because the `ThreadB` thread has already finished its work and died.  There's no other thread left to call `notify()`.

We call it a *race condition* when two (or more) threads race to do something, and the output of the program depends on which one gets there first.

Comment: You are right about race conditions but how main() is executing as a first thread everytime I am executing the program. I know its not necessary for other thread to execute but I have tried atleast 100 times and not getting any different results.

Comment: @NikhilArora, The Java Language Specification (JLS) _allows_ your program to give you the result that you see.  It also allows your program to work the other way that I described.  Which way it actually behaves could depend on many things; on the JVM version that you are running, on the operating system version, on the processor architecture, on what other processes are running on the machine, ...  That's why testing is not a reliable way to find problems in multi-threaded programs:  There are too many variables that you can't control.

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from that when wait() is encountered by the main() thread, how the executions shifts to run() in ThreadB.

**Before invoke wait()**

If it will invoke `wait method` next step, It means *main thread* hold *monitor* of object `b` currently. And if threadB want to execute *run() method* it will be blocked for waiting *monitor* of `b` which is hold by *main thread*.

**invoke wait()**

It means `main thread` release *monitor*, come into wait status, and advice *thread scheduler* re_dispatch. Then *ThreadB* can get *monitor* and make thing.

**notify()**

after finishing its job, threadB invoke **notify()** to wake up a single thread that is waiting on this object's *monitor*, here is *main thread*. And *main thread* will go on doing its work.

Comment: Why does main() reaches to the synchronized block even before ThreadB's run() is able to execute. How main() is able to execute the synchronized block on b (Object of class ThreadB).

Comment: @Nikhil Arora because `main thread` can get the *monitor of b*, then it can execute synchronized block and it has nothing with whether the run() of ThreadB is able to execute. And the synchronized block on **b** is executed by `thread b`  through executing  `b.start()`  not by `main thread`.